# case when with match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, switch-statement

Is there a way to make this work correctly with a case when?

```
field = "head_count_2011_10_75"
case field
  when match(/head_count_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i)
    puts "regex 1"
  when match(/dmi_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i)
    puts "regex 2
end
```

I know I can do it with if:

```
if field.match(/head_count_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i)
  puts "regex 1"
elsif field.match(/dmi_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i)
  puts "regex 2"
end
```

Just looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove the match:

```
field = "head_count_2011_10_75"
case field
  when /head_count_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i
    puts "regex 1"
  when /dmi_\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,4}/i
    puts "regex 2
end
```